# How long does one say Kaddish for a sibling?

Tags: sources-mekorot, death, mourning-aveilus, kaddish, family-members

There is discussion [here on MY](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11468/how-long-does-one-say-kaddish-for-a-parent) about saying Kaddish for parents and also [some discussion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8652/no-kaddish-for-a-sister) on Kaddish for a sister. One place [on the Chabad website](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/281618/jewish/Kaddish-Observances.htm) states that Kaddish should be said for 30 days for a sibling while another place [also on the Chabad website](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/514602/jewish/Who-Says-the-Kaddish-For-Whom.htm) (see comments below article) states that 11 months is customary.

For how long is Kaddish said for other relatives?  What sources back different traditions?

I am specifically concerned about the case of a deceased sibling, but I am also curious about minhag for Kaddish for other close relatives such as children.

Comment: My friend sadly said kaddish for a sibling for 30 days.  The parents of the deceased girl, also for 30.

Comment: I have been saying it, when I go to shul (about once per week), for about 8 months now for my brother...

Comment: @AdamRedwine, I'm sorry to learn that. But note that as this is a practical matter for you, you should consult an halachic expert, rather than rely on what you read on this site, to decide what to do.

Comment: I have never heard of any custom to say kaddish for longer than 30 days for anybody other than a parent. I am very sorry to hear about your loss.

Comment: My rabbi says 30 days, but did not give a source.

Comment: No source, but keep in mind that the person is only an Aveil - a mourner - for 30 days, except for parents.

Comment: Remember that there is no obligation to say kaddish.

Answer (score 1):

R Eliezer Melamed ([Peninei Halakha on Prayer, ch. 4](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/02-04-08/)) writes **the primary obligation of saying Kaddish rests upon the deceased's son** (incl. a minor). In case there is no son, the following may also say Kaddish, in order of priority: a grandson, a son-in-law, a father, brother or nephew. When none of these relatives can say Kaddish for the deceased, part of the inheritance money should be used to hire a God-fearing person to recite Kaddish for him.

Regarding its duration, he [writes](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/02-04-06/)

> **According to Ashkenazic custom, a mourner leads the services and says
> Kaddish for eleven months after a parent’s death**. [...] The
> Sephardic custom is to stop for the first week of the twelfth month
> and then continue to lead the services and say Kaddish until the
> anniversary of the death.

dinonline [writes](https://dinonline.org/2015/10/23/kaddish-for-sibling/)

> When there is a son saying Kaddish, the siblings generally do not say
> kaddish at all.

R David Brofsky (in his [book](https://korenpub.co.il/en/products/hilkhot-avelut) on Hilchos Aveilus, p. 237) writes exactly the same.